# How to extract list position based on Index Value

Tags: r, python-3.x

I have an R dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame("a"= c("123-wave-hi","234-boo-low","563-hi-dsa","897-op-ghhs"),
                 "b"= runif(4,2,10),
                 "c"= runif(4,5,20))
```

and would like to split 'a' by "-" and extract the segment with "numbers" [[i]][1] as a new variable 'idkey'. I was able to solve by (1) converting 'a' to character (2) splitting by "-" (3)setting up empty vector and appending via a loop then (4) cbinding the dataframe.  Shown below:

```
df$a <- as.character(df$a)
df$split <- strsplit(df$a , "-")
idkey<- vector()
for (i in seq(nrow(df))) {
  idkey[i]<- df$split[[i]][1]
}

df <- cbind(df,idkey)
```

Is there a less clumsy way to achieve this result?  Why doesn't :

```
df$rownum <- 1:nrow(df)
df$id <- df$split[[df$rownum]][1]
```

work?

Below is code for python that is not as messy, but I still would assume there's a way to do it without a loop?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["123-wave-hi","234-boo-low","563-hi-dsa","897-op-ghhs"],
                 "b": range(2,6),
                 "c": range(7,11)})


df['idkey']=[entry.split('-')[0] for entry in df['a']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$id <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$a), '-'), `[`, 1)
```

If you include an extra option when defining `df` (or set it as an option globally) you can avoid having to coerce columns to character with `as.character`

```
df <- data.frame("a"= c("123-wave-hi","234-boo-low","563-hi-dsa","897-op-ghhs"),
                 "b"= runif(4,2,10),
                 "c"= runif(4,5,20),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't you just want to extract the digits from `df$a`?

```
df$idkey <- gsub("(\\d+).*", "\\1", df$a)

            a        b        c idkey
1 123-wave-hi 6.050167 12.22999   123
2 234-boo-low 5.919546 17.62619   234
3  563-hi-dsa 7.193291 12.70553   563
4 897-op-ghhs 8.646451 12.94666   897
```

Comment: Or even simpler, `sub('-.*', '', df$a)`

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas you can do.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":["123-wave-hi","234-boo-low","563-hi-dsa","897-op-ghhs"],
                 "b": range(2,6),
                 "c": range(7,11)})


df['idkey']=  df['a'].str.split("-",  expand=True)[0]
print( df )
```

**Output:**

```
             a  b   c idkey
0  123-wave-hi  2   7   123
1  234-boo-low  3   8   234
2   563-hi-dsa  4   9   563
3  897-op-ghhs  5  10   897
```